# How to use wal_level in Postgres to set the recovery mode to simple for a database like how Microsoft SQL Server does it?

Tags: postgresql, recovery, log, recovery-model

In Microsoft SQL Server, `ALTER DATABASE CURRENT SET RECOVERY SIMPLE WITH NO_WAIT;` will set the recovery mode for a database to simple, so the transaction log file space can be re-used.

In Postgres, `wal_level` is available for that purpose.

1. Is `wal_level`'s `minimal` equivalent to SQL Server's `RECOVERY SIMPLE`?
2. How to set `wal_level` in Postgres command? - so far, Google Search tells me that `wal_level` is set in a configuration file.
3. Is it possible to set `wal_level` to `minimal` for a database? If yes, how?

Thank you.

Comment: So what does this "simple" mean? And [as documented in the manual](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/runtime-config-wal.html#RUNTIME-CONFIG-WAL-SETTINGS) `wal_level` is an instance (aka "cluster") wide setting. It can't be applied to individual databases.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name, "simple" means reusing transaction log file space, disabling the point in time recovery. The most recent restore point is either complete backup or the latest differential backup.

Can the `wal_level` be set in a Postgres command?

Comment: In Postgres you can only do [point-in-time recovery](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/continuous-archiving.html) if you enable/implement WAL archiving. Setting the correct `wal_level` is a prerequisite for that, but it will not activate WAL archiving. If I "minimal" only means that PITR is disabled, then this is the default mode in Postgres and you don't really need to change anything.

Comment: `then this is the default mode` - default was changed in postgresql 10: https://www.postgresql.org/message-id/E1cSR26-0002BY-9K@gemulon.postgresql.org

Comment: @Melkij: the wal_level default might have changed, but it you still need to take extra steps to implement PITR

Answer (score 0, accepted):

PostgreSQL works quite differently. Transaction log files will be removed with *all* `wal_level`s (as soon as the file is full and archived and a checkpoint has completed).

If you want to live without WAL archives, and all you need is crash recovery, you can set `wal_level` to `minimal`.

Comment: how to set `wal_level` to `minimal` in a Postgres command?

Comment: With `ALTER SYSTEM`. It needs a restart.